# Woocommerce : changing variation select with JS doesn't fire variation update

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on Woocommerce, using its product variations. Right now, I have to make a custom behavior on a `select` element. On a click on this `select`, it opens a modal window, and when I click on a element inside, it changes the original `select` value according to what I've clicked on.

So:

```
$('[data-remodal-id=format-modal] .format-list li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).index()+1;
    var modal = $('[data-remodal-id=format-modal]').remodal();
    modal.close();
    var value = $('#format option:eq('+index+')').val();
    $('#format').val('');
    $('#format option:eq('+index+')').attr('selected', 'selected');

    $('#format').val(value);
    $('.variations select').not('#format').find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.variations select').trigger('change');
    }, 300);
});
```

I was sure this would make the job, but it doesn't: nothing triggers the event that says to Woocommerce to update the variation id.

So, I made some heavy dirty stuff to make things work:

```
$(document).on('change', '#format', function () {
      console.log('format change 2');
      var value = $( ".variation_id" ).val();
      $(document).trigger('woocommerce_variation_select_change');
      $(document).trigger('show_variation');
      $( ".variation_id" ).val(' ');
      $( ".variation_id" ).val(value).change().trigger('change');
      $( ".variations_form" ).trigger( "show_variation");
      $( ".variations_form" ).trigger( "woocommerce_variation_select_change");
      $('.variations select').not('#format').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(' ');
        $(this).val(value);
        $(this).trigger('change');
      });
    });
```

But nothing in the code above works, but my `console.log('format change 2')` works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: try changing your click event to `$(document).on('click', '[your selector]', function(){ ... });`

Comment: Why would I? the click is working as expected (as the `console.log('format change 2')`, so the click did change the #format value)

Comment: You said nothing triggers your click event, and your `console.log` is in the `change` event for `#format` not the `click` event for `'[data-remodal-id=format-modal] .format-list li'`

Comment: ... as you can see, the click is changing the value of `#format`. If it does actually change its value, so it triggers the change event on `#format`. BTW, I never "said nothing triggers [my] click event", I said that the change event on my `#format`(which is a `select`) doesn't trigger Woocommerce variation update.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Do any of your triggers fire?

Comment: Did you manage to trigger the Woocommerce variation price update ? Could you please post the working snippet ?

Comment: I'll check that and get back to you.